# Problemas con los link en una instalación nueva de Laravel 10 con Jetstream en ambiente WLS2 (ubuntu)

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, routes

He instalado un proyecto nuevo con Laravel 10 sin problemas, luego instale Jetstream sin problemas, pero al momento de hacer clic en el enlace de Login, me aparece la pagina de 404
NO ENCONTRADO, y la ruta que muestra el navegador es la siguiente

http://proyecto.test/var/www/html/proyecto/public

Lo curioso es que si ejecuto el serve de laravel (php artisan serve) todo funciona bien.

La configuración del archivo host es la siguiente:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.proyecto.test
    ServerAlias proyecto.test
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/htlm/proyecto

    <Directory /var/www/html>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride all
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.proyecto.test.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/error.proyecto.test combined
```

El código del .htaccess (se encuentra en la carpeta public) es

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

mi archivo host de windows esta correcto

127.0.0.1    proyecto.test

::1          proyecto.test

¿Las rutas de laravel solo funcionan con el serve que trae?

Comment: Proba con `/var/www/html/proyecto/public` en DocumentRoot y Directory. O asegurate de que esten apuntando al directorio /public de tu proyecto